# The getter 'uid' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: uid

Tags: firebase, flutter

this error "
"The getter 'uid' was called on null.Receiver: nullTried calling: uid"

I Faced when i try to sign out from any screen "except home screen" ,

is there any solution for this problem ??

Wrapper :

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User_fb>(context);

    // return home or login
    if (user == null) {
      return Login();
    } else {
      print(user.uid);

      return Home();
    }
  }
}
```

auth :

```
Future Signinwithemailandpassword(var Res_email,var Res_Password) async{

    try{
        UserCredential result= await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: Res_email, password: Res_Password);
        User user = result.user;
        return _userfromfirebase(user);
    }catch(e){
      return null;
    }

}

Future signOut () async{
try{
  return await _auth.signOut();
}
catch(e){
print(e.toString());
print("error at signOut ");
return null;
}
}
```

main :

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(Main());
}

class Main extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainState createState() => _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<Main> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamProvider<User_fb>.value(
      value: Authservice().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
            shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
            highlightColor: Colors.transparent),
        home: Wrapper(),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Sign-out button :

```
ListTile(
                       leading: Icon(Ionicons.log_out_outline,
                           color: Color.fromRGBO(86, 197, 150, 1)),
                       title: Text('Log out'),
                       onTap: () async {
                         await _auth.signOut();
                       },
                     ),
```

console :

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Br(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<User_fb>], state: _QrState#24e19):
The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Qr file:///G:/AndroidStudioProjects/facem/lib/Screens/Home/Home.dart:687:67
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _QrState.build (package:my_compound/Screens/Qr/qr.dart:99:45)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4691:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens because user is null, So use null check operator.
something like this user?.uid or user.uid ?? '',

TIP: Alway use dart null safety when using flutter.